# what's the difference between firebase_messaging_web and firebase_messaging, which one should be used for crossplatform projects?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter project and I want to integrate firebase push notification in it. I checked [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) and I found two official packages for firebase_messaging the [default one](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and the [web version](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging_web). I'm planning to use same code-base for web, android and ios. In this case which package should I user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to integrate just firebase_messaging plugin it also support web as well, whenever you reached package home page always check its support label which are mentioned on top kindly check attached screenshot of website for your reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI1dX.png)

and firebase_messaging_web only use for web so, you just need to integrate firebase_messaging not both.